# How to solve a TypeError using LeaveOneOut

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been trying to work through the Vanderplass book and I have been stuck on this cell for days now:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)

from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=LeaveOneOut(len(X)))
scores
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<.  ipython-input-78-029fa0c72898> in <module>
  1 from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
 ----> 2 scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=LeaveOneOut(len(X)))
  3 scores

TypeError: LeaveOneOut() takes no arguments

import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
0.22.1'
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
Cameron

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, and a print out of your expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The error says `LeaveOneOut() takes no arguments`, but when you instantiated `LeaveOneOut` you passed it `len(X)` as an argument (in `LeaveOneOut(len(X))`).

If you change your `scores` line to the line below it should work:

```
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=LeaveOneOut())
```

However, note this warning from the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html):

> Note: LeaveOneOut() is equivalent to KFold(n_splits=n)...Due to the
> high number of test sets (which is the same as the number of samples)
> this cross-validation method can be very costly. For large datasets
> one should favor KFold, ShuffleSplit or StratifiedKFold.

In case that's not clear, that's a suggestion to use e.g. KFold with like n=5, which is usually going to serve you better than `LeaveOneOut`.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you Max!

Answer (score 0):

or, can also use

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)

from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=LeaveOneOut().split(X))
scores
```